# MySQL/Writing file error (Errcode 28) on creating database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3

I have the following error on execute sql file or creating database by entity framework code first approach

> Error writing file '.\dbdemo\ads.frm' (Errcode: 28)

On local database server it is working fine and creating database by EF Code First Approach but
on my website hosting server facing this problem.I have tried both techniques by executing sql file and creating database EF Code First Approach both failed.

Any idea how to solve this error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`perror` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/perror.html):

```
$ perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

Unless error codes are different on your system, your file system is full.

Refer [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html).

This [blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/26/how-to-diagnose-errors-in-the-mysql-error-log/) explains about the error. And [this](http://forum.percona.com/index.php?t=rview&goto=8133&th=2160) too.

> MySQL created a temporary table, using the MyISAM storage engine, and when the disk filled up, MyISAM got an error.

So try clearing the temp folder.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly. Refer the blog I've pointed to and clear the /temp folder. This error is because filesystem is full.