# Error code 28 in sql while creating table

Tags: mysql, create-table

Hey guys i have occurred an error while creating a file in mysql server using putty local host. I have also viewed answer for this question in this forum, but that didn't solve my problem. can any one please let me understand why is it happening?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE authors (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20));
```

`ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file './WS_ravi/authors.frm' (Errcode: 28)`

I have viewed this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694321/mysql-writing-file-error-errcode-28-on-creating-database), but still can't solve my problem.

Comment: first thought : are you sure you have free space on the mysql partition ?

Comment: yes i have free space on my mysql partition

Comment: As per old question you probably out of space. http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/68386

Comment: @sam under what OS the mysql is running?

Comment: my OS is windows vista, i'm using putty to access the local host server

Comment: @sam i assume you are logged in via root right? also try to create another table using shell or pma

Comment: yes i have looged in via root and using my WS